# Display a formatted list of columns from a data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to customize a displayed list of columns from a specified data frame.

Here is my data frame info:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/temp_1.csv')

col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
100,200,300,400,500
```

I want to output just the column list:

```
col1    col2    col3
col4    col5    col5
```

Specifically, I need to specify how many columns wide to display as well as to utilize other formatting options such as alphabetize (if that is possible)

I have tried the commands listed below, researched, and can't seem to find a solution. Seems like there would be a transpose function or something that would make this possible.

```
print df1.columns.values
print df1.columns.tolist()
dataframe.columns.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

data  = pandas.read_csv('sample.csv')
print data.columns.values
```

output:

```
[u'col1', u'col2', u'col3', u'col4']
```

and then manipulate the list based on your needs.

Comment: Actually, my output looks like:

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, my output looks like: ['col1' 'col2' 'col3' 'col4' 'col5'] if that matter. Also, the "manipulate the list based on your needs" part is what I am requesting assistance with. I don't want a horizontal listing but rather a vertical list or a vertical list in two columns.

Comment: is there a reason why you want the columns to be displayed vertically? @Tiberius

Comment: Thanks for your response. The end goal is to make a menu out of the columns. Choose 1 for col1, 2 for col2, etc. Also, I have run up against instances where information is displayed horizontally (such as this) and I thought it would be useful to know how to get it diaplayed vertically. This was a low hanging use case to gain that knowledge.